# Making a .pyw open a .py

Tags: python, subprocess

Alright, so here's the problem: I'm trying to make a .pyw file in which the exception handler opens a .py terminal. As far as I understand, you need to use a subroutine. However, I really can't get my head around that. Here's that I tried to do.

```
except:
    subprocess.run('alphareset.py')
```

Also, I have 2 local variables in a file that have the same name. How would I import them into other files?

Comment: Looks like you ask two independent questions. It would be better to make them two SO questions.

Comment: unrelated: do not use a bare `except:` -- log the error at the very least or catch a more specific exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the executable:

```
subprocess.run('python alphareset.py')
```

The association of the extension `*.py` with the Python executable on Windows typically does not work from within a subprocess.